# Inner Join only returning values if match is in all four tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following `INNER JOIN` statement and It is only returning results if all four tables have a match for the order number in them.

I need it to include every result in the main table `KC_Orders` regardless of the equivalent contents of each `INNER JOIN` tables in the `$sql`

I understand that this is the point of the INNER JOIN but I need it do something else.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `KC_Orders` 
                  INNER JOIN `KC_Payments` 
                        ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_Payments.orderNumber  
                  INNER JOIN `KC_OrderStatus`  
                        ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_OrderStatus.orderNumber 
                  INNER JOIN `KC_Statuses` 
                        ON KC_OrderStatus.statusID = KC_Statuses.statusID";
    $AllOrders = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a LEFT/RIGHT `OUTER JOIN`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left outer joins

```
SELECT *
FROM
    `KC_Orders`
    LEFT JOIN `KC_Payments`
        ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_Payments.orderNumber
    LEFT JOIN `KC_OrderStatus`
        ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_OrderStatus.orderNumber
    LEFT JOIN `KC_Statuses`
        ON KC_OrderStatus.statusID = KC_Statuses.statusID
```

If there is always a status available, you can keep the inner join for the `KC_Statuses` table

---

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    A
    LEFT JOIN B
        ON A.id = B.id
```

... means that all the records from `A` will be returned and only the records from `B` that match a record from `A`. Records from `A` are returned even when there is no matching record in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an `OUTER JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`.

If you want all rows from the KC_Orders table, then put that table first in the FROM clause, and use a LEFT JOIN on the other tables.  (The OUTER keyword is not required.) This will return all rows from the KC_Orders table, even if no matching row is found in the other tables. NULL values will be returned in place of value from "missing" rows.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `KC_Orders`
  LEFT 
  JOIN `KC_Payments`
    ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_Payments.orderNumber
  LEFT
  JOIN `KC_OrderStatus`
    ON KC_Orders.orderNumber = KC_OrderStatus.orderNumber
  LEFT 
  JOIN `KC_Statuses`
    ON KC_OrderStatus.statusID = KC_Statuses.statusID
```